# Getting issue while fetching the SIM numbers from Device

Tags: flutter, kotlin

In my flutter application using native kotlin code i am trying to fetch SIM numbers both SIM1 and SIM2 in my gradle file minimum sdk is 30
here is the function which i am have i am running the app on device having android 11 (tried with device having android 13 also)

```java
private fun getSimNumbers(): List<String> {
    val telephonyManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val subscriptionManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
    val subscriptionIds = mutableListOf<String>()

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Get subscription IDs for all slots
        val allSubscriptionIds = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList

        for (subscriptionInfo in allSubscriptionIds) {
            val subscriptionId = subscriptionInfo.subscriptionId
            val simNumber = subscriptionManager.getPhoneNumber(subscriptionId)
            if (simNumber != null) {
                subscriptionIds.add(simNumber)
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Request phone state permission if not granted
        requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    return subscriptionIds
}
```

and the following error i am getting

```java
E/AndroidRuntime(15898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(15898): Process: com.ebankchallenger, PID: 15898
E/AndroidRuntime(15898): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getPhoneNumber(I)Ljava/lang/String; in class Landroid/telephony/SubscriptionManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.telephony.SubscriptionManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
```

i am expecting to get both SIM1 number and SIM2 number

Comment: Pritam check your manifest file if you forgot to add the permission. Also check if the permission you are trying to use, does it have some minimum version constraint or not. Sometimes you need to handle permission request based on SDK version to make it compatible

Comment: `getPhoneNumber` is added in SDK 33